# how to add three default images to wordpress?

Tags: php

how to add three default images to wordpress **custom background**?

[image]

now, i want to add  three default images which can be selected one by the user.and it locates on the **upload Image** part.like this:

the default background image:

[image]

how do i do  thank you.

Comment: You should take a look at [http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_default_headers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_default_headers) - this is the function you need to setup your own images when using custom headers.

Answer (score 1):

You can see how the code is put to work in functions.php of TwentyEleven theme, line 135 - 195.

The codes to register your images are:

```
add_custom_image_header( 'twentyeleven_header_style', 'twentyeleven_admin_header_style', 'twentyeleven_admin_header_image' );
register_default_headers( array(
    'wheel' => array(
        'url' => '%s/images/headers/wheel.jpg',
        'thumbnail_url' => '%s/images/headers/wheel-thumbnail.jpg',
        /* translators: header image description */
        'description' => __( 'Wheel', 'twentyeleven' )
    ),
    'shore' => array(
        'url' => '%s/images/headers/shore.jpg',
        'thumbnail_url' => '%s/images/headers/shore-thumbnail.jpg',
        /* translators: header image description */
        'description' => __( 'Shore', 'twentyeleven' )
    )
) );
```